# WPF - Update UI/bindings on entity loaded

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, data-binding

Using WPF (MVVM, MVVM Light, Fody PropertyChanged), Entity Framework 6.1.3.

I have the following model.

```
// The INotifyPropertyChanged is generated by Fody.
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public string Name { get; set; }

   // Assume that INotifyPropertyChanged is properly implemented.
}
```

The following generic abstract view model:

```
public abstract class ViewModel<T> where T : class, new()
{
   public T Entity { get; set; }

   // Entity Framework repository (add, get, find, delete...)
   internal abstract IRegister<T> EntityRegister { get; set; }

}
```

And the Person View Model:

```
public class PersonViewModel : ViewModel<Person>
{
   // Person specific implementations...
   ...
}
```

And a simple WPF text box binding to the `Entity.Name` property.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Entity.Name,
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                                Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

**The Problem:**

Whenever I load (find) an Entity in my view model, e.g.:

```
Entity = EntityRegister.Find(10); // The Entity primary key.
```

the UI is not updated with the new loaded entity, I found a lot of posts suggesting invoking the `PropertyChanged` with `null` or `string.Empty` arguments to raise the `PropertyChanged` event for all properties.

Since I use Fody's PropertyChanged, the INotifyPropertyChanged is injected in my model only at runtime, so I have to call it dynamically.

```
dynamic entity = Entity;
entity.OnPropertyChanged(string.Empty);
```

I've tried by reflection too:

```
 var method = typeof(T).GetMethod("OnPropertyChanged");
 method.Invoke(Entity, new object[] { string.Empty });
```

They all run without exceptions, but they don't do anything, the UI binding is never refreshed, what am I doing wrong? The only way the textbox gets refreshed is when I focus it and press a key, then the textbox's value is refreshed.

Thanks.

**The Answer:**

Instead of invoking `OnPropertyChanged` for each property of the `Entity` object, just invoke `OnPropertyChanged` for the whole `Entity` object.

```
OnPropertyChanged("Entity");
```

Simple as that, the UI gets updated with the whole `Entity` object. Much easier, much simpler.

Comment: When debugging it's best not to assume anything.  For updates to happen there must be a Datacontext, Values to update, and Notification to the property system.  First question: When you set a breakpoint on the Entity assignment is there anything there?  Second question: Where is the datacontext set?  Third question... Property changed takes a name and value are they both being sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the UI isn't updating the properties on the entity is because the view doesn't recognize that they have changed, because the **entity property itself** hasn't told the UI that it has changed. (I hope that made sense)

If you are setting the entity like this:

```
Entity = EntityRegister.Find(10);
```

Then you must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the `Entity` property in your view model.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. It was just a matter of invoking `OnPropertyChanged` on `Entity` instead of it's properties. I thought that since the bindings are on the Entity's properties the `OnPropertyChanged` had to be invoked for each property instead of the whole object. Well, much easier. thanks again.